# scoped_session(sessionmaker()) or plain sessionmaker() in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, django, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQlAlchemy in my web project. What should I use - `scoped_session(sessionmaker())` or plain `sessionmaker()` - and why? Or should I use something else?

```
## model.py
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

engine = create_engine('mysql://dbUser:dbPassword@dbServer:dbPort/dbName',
pool_recycle=3600, echo=False)
metadata = MetaData(engine)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
Session.configure(bind=engine)
user = Table('user', metadata, autoload=True)

class User(object):
pass

usermapper = mapper(User, user)

## some other python file called abc.py
from models import *

def getalluser():
   session = Session()  
   session.query(User).all()
   session.flush()
   session.close()

## onemore file defg.py
from models import *

def updateuser():
   session = Session()  
   session.query(User).filter(User.user_id == '4').update({User.user_lname: 'villkoo'})
   session.commit()
   session.flush()
   session.close()
```

I create a `session = Session()` object for each request and I close it. Am I doing the right thing or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/06/orm/session.html?highlight=scoped_session#unitofwork-contextual) is recommended:

> the `scoped_session()` function is provided which produces a thread-managed registry of `Session` objects. It is commonly used in web applications so that a single global variable can be used to safely represent transactional sessions with sets of objects, localized to a single thread.

In short, use `scoped_session()` for thread safety.

Comment: thanks. And is it safe to open and close session object for each request ?

Comment: @northlondoner, not only its safe, but its recommended way of doing things, see http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#lifespan-of-a-contextual-session

Comment: @DanielKluev, that's a long page and it's been awhile since your comment, so maybe I'm reading the wrong thing or the page has changed, but it seems like the page is saying the opposite. To me, the "don't do this" code example seems very similar to the pattern used in the OP's code example, where a new session is being created for each database request. Is this a mixed terminology issue (webpage request vs database request) or is there some distinction between the two snippets that I'm missing?

Comment: @mmitchell the documentation as of now is maybe clearer: [Session is not a thread-safe object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-thread-safe), and [the same article pointed in tuomur answer](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions) is still there and valid, somehow explaining how its works, with a [web app explicit example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications).

Answer (score 12):

Scoped_session at every method will give you a thread of local session which you cannot obtain beforehand (like at the module level).It's not needed to open a new session in every method, You can use a global session , Create a session only when the global session is not available. i.e you can write a method which returns a session and add it to the **init**.py inside your package.

Answer (score 12):

Don't use scoped_session and don't use Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Just use `Session = sessionmaker()` held in a singleton/service class, and use `session = Session()` on every HTTP request to guarantee that a fresh connection is provided.

Thread Local storage is clumsy and involves holding state which doesn't play nicely with different web-server threading models. Better to stay stateless. See for example SqlAlchemy's documentation here mentioning not to forget to call `.remove()` if you are using `scoped_session`. Will anyone remember to do that?

Below is an excerpt from https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications:

> Using the above flow, the process of integrating the Session with the web application has exactly two requirements:
>
> - Create a single `scoped_session` registry when the web application first starts, ensuring that this object is accessible by the rest of the application.
> - Ensure that `scoped_session.remove()` is called when the web request ends, usually by integrating with the web framework’s event system to establish an “on request end” event.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, when using flask-sqlalchemy, the session object provided is by default a scoped session object.

[image]

http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#road-to-enlightenment

Answer (score 3):

I am looking into this myself, but I am not an expert.

My three points are:

1. SQLAlchemy docs provide a proposed approach using `scoped_session`, per Mr. Kluev's comment above, at this link: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications.
2. At that web location, the SQLAlchemy docs also say that it is "...strongly recommended that the integration tools provided with the web framework itself be used, if available, instead of `scoped_session`."
3. Flask-SQLAlchemy, for example, appears to claim that it takes care of this: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html#a-minimal-application

Comment: The problem with using Flask-SQLAlchemy is that it requires a db.Model base root for models.  If you have models that come from somewhere else other than your webapp then you're out of luck.  Hence, the need for scoped_session().