# Separate session objects for separate REST requests in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, session, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

I am using sqlalchemy (with MySQL as database) with cherrypy. I have created an engine which is application-wide. I read from [SqlAlchemy Sessions Doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#session-faq-whentocreate) that sessions are not thread-safe. Does that mean I should create a separate session for each REST request? If so, does session use default connection pool in sqlalchemy (with pool_size=5 and max_overflow=10)? Does this mean that 15(pool_size + max_overflow) concurrent requests can be handled without a problem? Also, does a single connection-pool belong to sqlalchemy Engine or a single Session object?

Comment: This question may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519546/scoped-sessionsession-maker-or-plain-session-maker-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to provide the part of your code. But first of all should read [Official doc about Thread-local Sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/contextual.html#unitofwork-contextual)

As I can understand we need to use separate session for each thread. When I tried to make my first applications I didn't do like this and sometimes I got errors. 
There is a [SQLA tool](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/SQLA) for cherrpy, you can use this tool or write more simple for yourself.

Comment: You should add essential parts of your links as part of your answer.